# IIS 6 : redirect the pages in asp

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, iis-6

I am using IIS 6 and classic ASP. I don't have access of hosting server. I want to create redirect pages.

```
www.example.com/location/123
```

to

```
www.example.com/location.asp?id=123
```

Do I need to create some function in `global.asa` file?

Answer (score 0):

There's really only a couple of ways to achieve this if you're using classic ASP:

1. If your hosting provider provides access to a url rewriter as part of their package (ISAPI_Rewrite for example) then you could rewrite the friendly urls.
2. If your hosting provider doesn't provide support for a url rewriter but does allow you to change the `404` error handler to a custom script then you could parse the url then do a `Server.Transfer` to `location.asp?id=xxxx`. Here's an article describing such a mechanism:

   http://www.stronghost.co.uk/URL-Rewrites-and-IIS-/-ASP/B7.htm

   Most providers will allow you to do this as it's a fairly basic hosting requirement. You might need to ask them to do this in a support ticket if their control panel doesn't allow this.

Answer (score -1):

In the page load using c# you could do

`Response.Redirect("~/location.asp?id=123");`